# 2D lists of parameters to lapply

Tags: r, arraylist, multidimensional-array, 2d, lapply

Sadly was unable to realize how to do it in R, but the idea seams simple.

What I want is a list of pairs of numbers under a range where the fist pair is the first value and the sum of first pair with the maximum length, in the end I should have something like:

```
somefun <- function(start, end, step){...}
l <- somefun (5, 30, 5)
l 
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] 5
#
#[[1]][[2]]
#[1] 10
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] 11
#
#[[2]][[2]]
#[1] 16
#
#[[3]]
#[[3]][[1]]
#[1] 17
#
#[[3]][[2]]
#[1] 22
#
#[[4]]
#[[4]][[1]]
#[1] 23
#
#[[4]][[2]]
#[1] 28
#
#[[5]]
#[[5]][[1]]
#[1] 29

#[[5]][[2]]
#[1] 30
```

So, the final list should have the first `start` and the last `end` values, but the difference within each list shouldn't be larger than the step.

Also, I don't know if it could be the best way, but my objective is pass this values with `lapply` to build a plot using grid with `gredExtra::grid.arrange`

So the list should fit in this code

```
p_list = lapply(myRanges, function(a,b){
  my_gg_function(myData[a:b], font=f)
})

do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, c(p_list, ncol=2))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
somefun <- function(start, end, step){
  starts <- seq(start, end, step+1)
  ends <- pmin(starts + step, end)
  mapply(list, starts, ends, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
}
somefun(5, 30, 5)
```

We just use a basic `seq()` and trim as needed.

Comment: unfortunately this one don't generate a output which fit with `lapply`. See the example `lapply(somefun(1, 36, 5), function(x){cat(paste(x[[1]], x[[2]], sep = "#"))}`

Comment: @AurelianoGuedes I'm not sure what you are showing in your example. The `cat()` function returns `NULL` so you get a list with a bunch of NULLs but the values are printed out at the top of that list as a side effect from the `cat()`. That line seems to work just fine.